# Is there a directory that will place items in the root of _site on build?

Tags: jekyll

I have a bunch of static files (basically favicons, apple-site-icons, etc) that I want to be at the root of `_site` when it's built. Currently they're just sitting at the root of my main code folder (along with `_posts`, `_scss`, `_layouts`, etc). It builds fine but it would be nice to move them into a subdirectory so the main directory isn't cluttered up (it's an OCD thing).

Is there any folder where I can put these items so they automatically copy to the root of `_site` when I build? I know I can write a script to do this and trigger it after the build, and there's probably an extension I could lean on, but I'm looking for a solution that just automatically moves them when I run `jekyll build` for simplicity.

NBD if I can't do it, just curious because I'm kind of a neat freak.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Jekyll allows you to do exactly that using permalinks.

> Permalinks are the output path for your pages, posts, or collections. They allow you to structure the directories of your source code different from the directories in your output.

A simple example extracted from the [official page](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/permalinks/) is a case where you have `/my-pages/about-me.html` with the front matter as follows:

```
---
permalink: /about/
---
```

This way you specify the output url. In this example, you could access it in local with `localhost:4000/about/`

Comment: Thanks but this doesn't work for images (like png or ico) because I can't specify front matter as they aren't text. Otherwise this would absolutely work, I've been doing it in a lot of other places (like my about, legal, privacy, and other pages). I appreciate that you took the time to chime in though, this answer will probably help other folks. Cheers!

Comment: You're right, I didn't take that on count ^^". I think @Ross answer can be the one.

Answer (score 0):

The `source` option. You can specify this in your `_config.yml` or as a command line option (https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/options/). How you set this has slightly different requirements/implications.

First, move everything that belongs to the Jekyll site into a folder (e.g. "src").

Then set one of these up (assuming you have a Gemfile):

**Command line option with root Gemfile:**

- Keep `Gemfile` in the root folder
- Run `bundle install`
- Run `bundle exec jekyll serve --source src`

**Command line option with nested Gemfile:**

- Run `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=src/Gemfile bundle install`
- Run `BUNDLE_GEMFILE=src/Gemfile bundle exec jekyll serve --source src`

**Config file option:**

- Keep `Gemfile` and `_config.yml` in the root folder
- Add `source: src` somewhere in your `_config.yml`
- Run `bundle install`
- Run `bundle exec jekyll serve`

Each solution here might work better with other external services building your site. There are likely other ways to set this up, but this should get you started.